# Persistence for an ASP.NET 5 Web API running in a Docker container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, persistence

I have an ASP.NET 5 Web API running in a Docker container. It happily accepts web requests and can be deployed anywhere you can install Docker. Now I'd like to link my Web API container to a NoSQL backend container that also runs in a container. I considered MongoDB, but as far as I can tell Mongo does not yet have a .NET core compatible C# driver.

If that's not true, I am happy to be contradicted.

**How are folks doing persistence for ASP.NET 5 web applications?** Are there any other popular NoSQL backends on dockerhub with a .NET core compatible C# driver?